# REST web service in python 3?

Tags: python, web-services, rest, python-3.x

I'm new to the python world and I'm currently in a new project using it. So since we we're there to learn, we chose to start with python 3. Now, we need to make a RESTful web service. After reading a few, I found out that the most used framework for web services is Django... and I also read on the Django website that it does not yet supports python 3.

Is there any other API that I could use in order to make a RESTful web service?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[CherryPy](http://www.cherrypy.org/) has a Python 3 branch.  Not sure how advanced it is, but if Fu-manchu passes by this question, he will be able to tell you.

Comment: Yes, CherryPy 3.2 has a version for Python 3. It's currently at "release candidate" status, but should be finalized soon. Feel free to use it now. You can get it at http://download.cherrypy.org/cherrypy/3.2.0rc1/ (the 'py3' builds).

Answer (score 0):

The [Bottle](http://bottle.paws.de/page/start) framework claims to work with Python 3.  You might inquire on their [google group](http://groups.google.de/group/bottlepy) for details.

Answer (score 0):

I really like to use bottle and run it on cherrypy.  This is really easy, do everything per bottle instructions, and then in the run line, tell it to use cherrypy as it's server.

Exampple:

```
app.run(host='localhost',
        port=8080,
        server='cherrypy',
        reloader=True,
        debug=True)
```